# Time series with date format %Y-%m

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data with two columns of values and one column of date in %Y-%m format. I learnt to use xts to transform dataframe to time series data. However, the result doesn't output the date correctly. In the end, I need to plot cnt vs YrMon(ordered by time on x-axis) and total vs YrMon.

```
    YrMon   cnt        total
1:  2016-08 14.42857  705.071429
2:  2016-09 13.21429    3.642857
3:  2017-04 13.28571  344.000000
4:  2016-07 14.21429  673.142857
.....
```

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does adding a dummy day and then converting the column into date help? Like this

```
paste(data$YrMon,"-01",sep = "")
data$YrMon <- as.Date(data$YrMon)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works!